# Calculate the union of an ordered set in C++

Tags: c++, class, types, stl, set

I would like to combine three variants of runlength encoding schemes (the runlengths are cumulated, hence the variant).
Let's start with two of them:
The first one contains a list of booleans, the second a list of counters. Let's say that the first looks as follows: (value:position of that value):

```
[(true:6), (false:10), (true:14), (false:20)]
// From 1 to 6, the value is true
// From 7 to 10, the value is false
// From 11 to 14, the value is true
// From 15 to 20, the value is false
```

The second looks as follows (again (value:position of that value)):

```
[(1:4), (2:8), (4:16), (0:20)]
// From 1 to 4, the value is 1
// From 5 to 8, the value is 2
// From 9 to 16, the value is 4
// From 17 to 20, the value is 0
```

As you can see, the positions are slightly different in both cases:

```
Case 1 : [6, 10, 14, 20]
Case 2 : [4, 8, 16, 20]
```

I would like to combine those "position arrays", by calculating their union:

```
[4, 6, 8, 10, 14, 16, 20]
```

Once I have this, I would derive from there the new schemes:

```
[(true:4), (true:6), (false:8), (false:10), (true:14), (false:16), (false:20)]
[(1:4), (2:6), (2:8), (4:10), (4:14), (4:16), (0:20)]
```

I would like to know: is there any C++ standard type/class which can contain the "arrays" [6, 10, 14, 20] and [4, 8, 16, 20], calculate their union and sort it?

Thanks
Dominique

Comment: Are you looking for [set_union](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_union) ?

Comment: [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to know: is there any C++ standard type/class which can contain the "arrays" [6, 10, 14, 20] and [4, 8, 16, 20], calculate their union and sort it?

I guess you didn't do much research before asking this question. There's a class template that manages an ordered set, called `set`. If you add all the elements of two sets into a single set, you will have the union.

```
std::set<int> s1{6, 10, 14, 20};
std::set<int> s2{4, 8, 16, 20};

std::set<int> union = s1;
union.insert(s2.begin(), s2.end());
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use [`std::set_union`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_union) from `<algorithm>`.

I use a `std::vector<int>` here, but it can be any template type.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
  std::vector<int> a{6, 10, 14, 20};
  std::vector<int> b{4, 8, 16, 20};
  std::vector<int> c;

  std::set_union(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end(), std::back_inserter(c));
  for(auto e: c) {
    std::cout << e << ' ';
  }
  std::cout << '\n';
}
```

[Here's the ideone](http://ideone.com/nDaWFA)

If you'd like to maintain only two `std::vector`s without introducing `c`, you could simply append `b` to `a`, sort the array, then call `std::unique` on `a`. There *may* be a clever way to do this in `O(n)`, but here's the naïve approach:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<int> a{6, 10, 14, 20};
  std::vector<int> b{4, 8, 16, 20};

  a.insert(a.end(), b.begin(), b.end());

  std::sort(a.begin(), a.end());
  auto last = std::unique(a.begin(), a.end());
  a.erase(last, a.end());

  for(auto e: a) {
    std::cout << e << ' ';
  }
  std::cout << '\n';
}
```

[Here's the ideone](http://ideone.com/EKCBGG)

Finally, you can use `std::inplace_merge` instead of `std::sort`. In the worst case it's `O(nlogn)` like `std::sort`, but in the best case it's `O(n)`. Quite an increase in performance:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<int> a{6, 10, 14, 20};
  std::vector<int> b{4, 8, 16, 20};

  auto a_size = a.size();

  a.insert(a.end(), b.begin(), b.end());

  // merge point is where `a` and `b` meet: at the end of original `a`.    
  std::inplace_merge(a.begin(), a.begin() + a_size, a.end());

  auto last = std::unique(a.begin(), a.end());
  a.erase(last, a.end());

  for(auto e: a) {
    std::cout << e << ' ';
  }
  std::cout << '\n';
}
```

[Here's the ideone](http://ideone.com/5qou9s)

Comment: This will not be safe because it the iterator will be invalidated. I can update with another option in a minute.

Comment: Instead of sorting the array, `std::inplace_merge` may be used.

Comment: @Jarod42 That's beautiful. I knew `std::merge`, but knew it wasn't in-place. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

As hinted at by [erip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35131899/2920343), there is an algorithm that only requires you to iterate both vectors once. As a precondition, both of them have to be sorted at the start. You can use that fact to always check which one is smaller, and only append a value from that vector to the result. It also allows you to remove duplicates, because if you want to add a value, that value will only be a duplicate if it is the last value added to the result vector.

I have whipped up some code; I haven't run extensive tests on it, so it may still be a little buggy, but here you go:

```
// Assume a and b are the input vectors, and they are sorted.
std::vector<int> result;

// We know how many elements we will get at most, so prevent reallocations
result.reserve(a.size() + b.size());

auto aIt = a.cbegin();
auto bIt = b.cbegin();

// Loop until we have reached the end for both vectors
while(aIt != a.cend() && bIt != b.cend())
{
    // We pick the next value in a if it is smaller than the next value in b.
    // Of course we cannot do this if we are at the end of a.
    // If b has no more items, we also take the value from a.
    if(aIt != a.end() && (bIt == b.end() || *aIt < *bIt))
    {
        // Skip this value if it equals the last added value
        // (of course, for result.back() we need it to be nonempty)
        if(result.size() == 0 || *aIt != result.back())
        {
            result.push_back(*aIt);
        }
        ++aIt;
    }
    // We take the value from b if a has no more items, 
    // or if the next item in a was greater than the next item in b
    else
    {
        // If we get here, then either aIt == a.end(), in which case bIt != b.end() (see loop condition)
        // or bIt != b.end() and *aIt >= *bIt.
        // So in either case we can safely dereference bIt here.
        if(result.size() == 0 || *bIt != result.back())
        {
            result.push_back(*bIt);
        }
        ++bIt;
    }
}
```

It allows some optimizations in both style and performance but I think it works overall.

Of course if you want the result back in `a`, you can either modify this algorithm to insert directly into `a`, but it's probably faster to keep it like this and just `a.swap(result)` at the end.

You can see it in action [here](http://ideone.com/Alg9J1).

Comment: @Jarod42 good catch I swapped the condition in the first `if` to avoid that, and added some comments to the `else` to explain why it is not possible to dereference an invalid `bIt` there. If you see any more errors, feel free to correct them.